# Toolbar in non-AppCompat project not inflating

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar

I tried to implement my toolbar with my activity but it's not inflating and keeps showing an error. My project does not use AppCompat but I'm not sure whether or not that is also the vause of the error.

> Error inflating class android.widget.Toolbar

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar customToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1line);
        setActionBar(customToolbar);

        //add back arrow to toolbar
        if (getActionBar() != null){
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        TextView mTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.select_a_destination_station));
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        mTitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        mTitle.setSingleLine(true);
        mTitle.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

**toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_1line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/singleline_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_singleline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_objects"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

In the Toolbar_layout

**One way**

**change**

```
<android.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_1line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
</android.widget.Toolbar>
```

**to**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_1line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In the java code

**change**

```
Toolbar customToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1line);
setActionBar(customToolbar);

//add back arrow to toolbar
if (getActionBar() != null){
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

**to**

```
Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1line);
setSupportActionBar(customToolbar);
//add back arrow to toolbar
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

**Another way**

**change**

```
<android.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_1line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
</android.widget.Toolbar>
```

**to**

```
<Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_1line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
</Toolbar>
```

It's easy.